# CASE statement in SQL giving not proper values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having abnormal values when I run this part in my sql code. SQL syntax wise, everything is okay with this?

```
select
  COUNT(CASE WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  
    THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END)           AS successfulbillinghits,
  SUM(CASE WHEN  bt.idBillingStatus = 2 
    THEN price
      ELSE 0.0 END)  
                  AS old_revenue    
from table
```

---

Overall Query is this. The result of successfulbillinghits should be equal to timesbilled

```
SELECT
  cs.idCustomerSubscription,
  cs.msisdn,
  pro.name                       AS promoterName,
  c.name                         AS ClubName,
  c.idClub                       AS ClubID,
  o.name                        AS operatorName,
  o.idOperator                   AS OperatorID,
  co.name                        AS country,
 -- cu.customerSince               AS CustomerSince,
  cs.subscribeddate              AS subscribeddate,
 -- cs.subscriptionNotificationSent AS SubNotificationSent,
 -- cs.eventId                     AS EventId,
  cs.unsubscribeddate           AS unsubscribeddate,
  cs.firstBillingDate            AS FirstBillingDate,
  cs.lastBilledDate              As LastBilledDate,
  cs.lastAttemptDate             AS LastAttemptDate,
  -- smp.code                       AS packageName,
  -- o.mfactor                      AS mmfactor,
  -- cs.idSubscriptionSource        AS SubscriptionChannel,
  -- cs.idUnsubscribeSource         AS UnsubscriptionChannel,
  -- DATE(bt.creationDate)          AS BillingCreationDate,
  -- bt.price                       AS pricePerBilling,
  -- cs.lastRetryDate               As LastRetryDate,
  -- cs.lastRenewalDate             AS LastRenewalDate,
  -- cs.isActive                    AS ActiveStatus,
  -- COUNT(bt.idBillingTransaction) AS BillingAttempts,
  curr.idcurreny_symbol          AS CurrencyID,
  curr.symbol                    AS currency,
  date(bt.creationDate)          AS BillingDate,
  cs.lastBilledAmount            As LastBilledAmount,
  cs.timesbilled,
  price,
 --  sum(price),
  -- revenueShareAmountLocal,
  -- o.mfactor,
  -- count(IFF (bt.idBillingStatus = 2,1,0)) as otherversion,

  count(CASE WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  
    THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END)           AS successfulbillinghits,
  SUM(CASE WHEN  bt.idBillingStatus = 2 
    THEN price 
      ELSE 0.0 END)  
                  AS old_revenue   

FROM
  customersubscription cs
  LEFT JOIN
  billing_transaction bt
    ON CONVERT(cs.msisdn USING latin1) = bt.msisdn 
       AND cs.idClub = bt.idClub
       AND bt.creationDate BETWEEN cs.SubscribedDate AND COALESCE(cs.UnsubscribedDate, now())

  INNER JOIN customer cu ON (cs.idCustomer = cu.idcustomer)
  INNER JOIN operator o ON (o.idoperator = cu.idoperator)
  INNER JOIN country co ON (co.`idCountry` = o.idCountry)
  INNER JOIN curreny_symbol curr ON (curr.idcurreny_symbol = co.idCurrencySymbol)
  LEFT JOIN Promoter pro ON cs.idPromoter = pro.id  
  INNER JOIN club_operator_relationships cor ON cor.clubId = cs.idClub 
  INNER JOIN club c ON c.idClub = cs.idClub
  -- INNER JOIN operator op ON op.idOperator = cu.idOperator


WHERE
-- (cs.timesbilled > 0 and cs.subscribeddate < '2016-09-01 00:00:00' ) 
cs.subscribeddate between '2017-04-20 00:00:00' and '2017-04-21 00:00:00'
  AND cs.idClub IN (39) 
GROUP BY idCustomerSubscription, ClubName, operatorName, promoterName
```

Successfulbillinghits is much greater than timesbilled in the result

Comment: what is 'bt' in your query signifies?

Comment: Describe "abnormal" - are you getting values that are some integer multiple of the expected values? If so, the problem is almost certainly with an under-constrained `join` (that you've not shown us)

Comment: @hammy could you add current and expected outputs?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `COUNT`use `SUM`, as `count` counts blanks or nulls also

```
  select
  SUM(CASE WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  
    THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END)           AS successfulbillinghits,
  SUM(CASE WHEN  bt.idBillingStatus = 2 
    THEN price
      ELSE 0.0 END)  
                  AS old_revenue    
from table
```

Comment: same problem. So, ignoring the logics and all, the case statement it self is fine? is there an alternative to do it?

Comment: Yeah, CASE statement is fine. Lot of alternatives exist. You can use inner queries and calculate 2 values separately and then fetch them in the outer query

Comment: @hammy - at the moment, key details such as *what you're trying to do*, what results you expected, what results you received, etc, are only in your head. How can you expect us to suggest alternatives when we don't know what the goal is nor why the current code isn't meeting it?

Comment: Try this:- group by   cs.idCustomerSubscription,   cs.msisdn,   pro.name                      ,   c.name                        ,   c.idClub                      ,   o.name                        ,   o.idOperator                   ,   co.name                        ,   cs.subscribeddate              ,   cs.unsubscribeddate           ,   cs.firstBillingDate            ,   cs.lastBilledDate             ,   cs.lastAttemptDate             ,   curr.idcurreny_symbol         ,   curr.symbol              ,   date(bt.creationDate)          ,   cs.lastBilledAmount      ,   cs.timesbilled,   price

Comment: Tried. didnt get through. Is it the a problem with the grouping?

Comment: can you email your skype id at iqbalwari@gmail.com?

Comment: I debugged. its showing the same value in billingattempts and successfulbilling

Comment: The billingstatus=2 is not counting

Comment: Use Sum not count like this:-

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  
    THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `CASE`, you can use `WHERE` clause with these aggregate functions, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `successfulbillinghits`, SUM(price) as `old_revenue`
FROM table bt
WHERE bt.idBillingStatus = 2;
```